# issue writing regex for 6 char code

Tags: python, regex

I have a file with the data in the following format:

```
   1 AA/BB                  0C89JG
   2 ABANO/ANA VICTORIA     F12LFJ
   3 ABBOUDLASTNAME/ABBOUDF DWPTHC
   4 ABDALLAH/SIJAM         H0ZDM9
   5 ABDEL MESSIH/DINA      T0SF8N
   6 ABHISHEK/PRAMANIK      7SLKXV
   7 ABHYANKAR/DHANANJAY    7SM0BV
   8 ABOUSALAMA/FEMKE       LTTRQC
   9 ABRAMOVA/NATALIA       77LCPZ
  10 ABRANTES/JOAO          KXZC7Q
  11 ABRATH/LUC             D5J99J
  12 ABREO/HECTOR           CXDH4G
  13 ABREU/ANDREA           242GRC
  14 ABREU/MARCELO          2436R7
  15 ABREU/VANDA            3HDNQQ
  16 ABTS/NATHALIE          DSK9TN
  17 ABTS/NATHALIE          FZ0LN4
```

And I am trying to extract the last 6 characters e.g. FZ0LN4 from line 17.
The regular expression that I have come up with is:

```
([0-9]{1,5})([A-Z /]) ([0-9A-Z]{6})
```

But it isn't working at the moment. Can anyone please point out what is the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues:

- You're not matching some of the whitespaces.
- The `[A-Z /]` lacks a repetition operator.

I'd rewrite the regex like so:

```
In [8]: re.match(r'\s*(\d+)\s*([A-Z /]+?)\s*(\w+)$', '  15 ABREU/VANDA            3HDNQQ').groups()
Out[8]: ('15', 'ABREU/VANDA', '3HDNQQ')
```

If you just need the last six characters, then there's no need for a regex:

```
In [15]: s = '  15 ABREU/VANDA            3HDNQQ'

In [16]: s[-6:]
Out[16]: '3HDNQQ'
```

Comment: much better than mine :)
but it will fail at the 2nd record :(

Comment: @RaheelAliBaloch: Good point, I overlooked the space. Fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

If you just need the string at the end of the line you can use a much simpler regex, such as: `\b\w{6}\b$`

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking just for the last line (17)?  If so, re.search the whole string:

```
import re
myString="""
   1 AA/BB                  0C89JG
   2 ABANO/ANA VICTORIA     F12LFJ
   3 ABBOUDLASTNAME/ABBOUDF DWPTHC
   4 ABDALLAH/SIJAM         H0ZDM9
   5 ABDEL MESSIH/DINA      T0SF8N
   6 ABHISHEK/PRAMANIK      7SLKXV
   7 ABHYANKAR/DHANANJAY    7SM0BV
   8 ABOUSALAMA/FEMKE       LTTRQC
   9 ABRAMOVA/NATALIA       77LCPZ
  10 ABRANTES/JOAO          KXZC7Q
  11 ABRATH/LUC             D5J99J
  12 ABREO/HECTOR           CXDH4G
  13 ABREU/ANDREA           242GRC
  14 ABREU/MARCELO          2436R7
  15 ABREU/VANDA            3HDNQQ
  16 ABTS/NATHALIE          DSK9TN
  17 ABTS/NATHALIE          FZ0LN4
"""

m = re.search("(\S{6})$", myString)
if m:
    print m.group(1)
```

If you need to find the specific line, you should iterate over the lines individually:

```
for line in myString.split("\n"):
    m = re.search("^\s*17\s*.*(\S{6})$", line)
    if m:
        print m.group(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is easily done without a regex:

```
st='''\
   1 AA/BB                  0C89JG
   2 ABANO/ANA VICTORIA     F12LFJ
   3 ABBOUDLASTNAME/ABBOUDF DWPTHC
   4 ABDALLAH/SIJAM         H0ZDM9
   5 ABDEL MESSIH/DINA      T0SF8N
   6 ABHISHEK/PRAMANIK      7SLKXV
   7 ABHYANKAR/DHANANJAY    7SM0BV
   8 ABOUSALAMA/FEMKE       LTTRQC
   9 ABRAMOVA/NATALIA       77LCPZ
  10 ABRANTES/JOAO          KXZC7Q
  11 ABRATH/LUC             D5J99J
  12 ABREO/HECTOR           CXDH4G
  13 ABREU/ANDREA           242GRC
  14 ABREU/MARCELO          2436R7
  15 ABREU/VANDA            3HDNQQ
  16 ABTS/NATHALIE          DSK9TN
  17 ABTS/NATHALIE          FZ0LN4'''

for line in st.splitlines():
    print line.split()[-1]
```

Prints:

```
0C89JG
F12LFJ
DWPTHC
H0ZDM9
T0SF8N
7SLKXV
7SM0BV
LTTRQC
77LCPZ
KXZC7Q
D5J99J
CXDH4G
242GRC
2436R7
3HDNQQ
DSK9TN
FZ0LN4
```

Or, if you just want the 'nth' one, something like this:

```
>>> li=[line.split()[-1] for line in st.splitlines()]
>>> li[-1]
'FZ0LN4'
>>> li[-2]
'DSK9TN'    # etc etc
```

Or, if you *really* want a regex:

```
>>> re.findall(r'\s(\S{6})$',st,re.MULTILINE)
['0C89JG', 'F12LFJ', 'DWPTHC', 'H0ZDM9', 'T0SF8N', '7SLKXV', '7SM0BV', 'LTTRQC', '77LCPZ', 'KXZC7Q', 'D5J99J', 'CXDH4G', '242GRC', '2436R7', '3HDNQQ', 'DSK9TN', 'FZ0LN4']
>>> re.findall(r'\s(\S{6})$',st,re.MULTILINE)[-1]
'FZ0LN4'
```

Answer (score 0):

use the `$` character for the and of the line and `\S` for non-whiteSpace characters

```
import re
>>> s = s = '''   1 AA/BB                  0C89JG
   2 ABANO/ANA VICTORIA     F12LFJ
   3 ABBOUDLASTNAME/ABBOUDF DWPTHC
   4 ABDALLAH/SIJAM         H0ZDM9
   5 ABDEL MESSIH/DINA      T0SF8N
   6 ABHISHEK/PRAMANIK      7SLKXV
   7 ABHYANKAR/DHANANJAY    7SM0BV
   8 ABOUSALAMA/FEMKE       LTTRQC
   9 ABRAMOVA/NATALIA       77LCPZ
  10 ABRANTES/JOAO          KXZC7Q
  11 ABRATH/LUC             D5J99J
  12 ABREO/HECTOR           CXDH4G
  13 ABREU/ANDREA           242GRC
  14 ABREU/MARCELO          2436R7
  15 ABREU/VANDA            3HDNQQ
  16 ABTS/NATHALIE          DSK9TN
  17 ABTS/NATHALIE          FZ0LN4'''

>>> re.findall('\\S{6}$', s, re.MULTILINE)
['0C89JG', 'F12LFJ', 'DWPTHC', 'H0ZDM9', 'T0SF8N', '7SLKXV', '7SM0BV', 'LTTRQC', '77LCPZ', 'KXZC7Q', 'D5J99J', 'CXDH4G', '242GRC', '2436R7', '3HDNQQ', 'DSK9TN', 'FZ0LN4']
```